# How to feed sequences to a TensorFlow Keras model?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I'd like to train a model, that assigns some score to a variable-sized sequence of events. Each sequence is in its own file, and I start with a list of (file name, target score).

So I do something like this:

```
dataset = fileNames.map((fileName, score) => (new CsvDataset(x), score));
```

What I get is : `NotImplementedError : The Dataset.map() transformation does not currently support nested datasets as outputs`

I am using TensorFlow 1.10.

Question is: how do I load and feed pairs of (sequence, training score) to a model? Is `tf.data` even a viable approach?

Comment: It was unclear, apparently, but `fileNames` is a already a  `Dataset`.

Comment: Then you can use `tf.data.Dataset.zip((dataset_x, dataset_y))`

Comment: The problem is not, that I don't know how to zip two datasets. Problem is to convert a `Dataset` consisting of (1,) tensors, which contains csv file names into a `Dataset`, consisting of datasets, where a single nested `Dataset`  consists of rows of the corresponding file. Seems that `.map` does not support that. Should I be converting every `.csv` file into a `Tensor` instead?

Comment: You can use `tf.decode_csv` on whatever dataset shape you use. Edited answer, hope I understood you correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create dataset object prior to using amy map function. Dataset API is a perfectly viable option.

```
dataset = tf.contrib.data.make_csv_dataset(filenames)
```

This function is from 1.10 version. You can then use `dataset.zip((dataset, labels))` to add labels, or map some parse function using `dataset.map()`
More on this 
https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset
                                 https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.10/api_docs/python/tf/contrib/data/make_csv_dataset

EDIT 1:

```
If you need to parse file by file you can do 
x = ['1.csv', '2.csv']
y = [label_1, labels_2]

def parse_csv_func(data, label):
    return tf.decode_csv(data, ['float32']*number_of_columns)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x, y))
dataset = dataset.map(parse_csv_func)
```

output: `[b'1.csv'] label_1`

This dataset object will contain path to csv filename and corresponding label, so you can apply whatever parse function to a separate file you want. If dataset is nested, you can flatten it.

Comment: Looks like `make_csv_dataset` is very broken in `1.10`. However, after upgrading to `1.12`, and trying `make_csv_dataset(filenames)`, I believe it is not what I am looking for. The `dataset` in your example ends up just being a concatenation of all rows in all my `.csv` files. What I expect to see is a dataset, where each entry corresponds to a file, and has many rows. Please, take a look at the following pseudo Python code I am trying to reproduce with `Dataset` APIs: https://pastebin.com/SdNSmv1r

Comment: I must restate, that I might be completely misunderstanding of what I am supposed to pass to the LSTM in the first place.

Comment: but that's exactly what I am trying to do in the question, where my `parse_csv_func` is basically another `make_csv_dataset` (but calling constructor instead of factory) with a single file name.